# How to get one data table from Stored procedure that has multiple select statements using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two `select` statements in my stored procedure:

```
 alter proc multiple

 select * from table-one
 select * from table-two
```

Now how to get the data of table-one only by executing the stored procedure?

Comment: In the title you ask for data from both selects but in the question you only want data from one. What is your question?

Comment: One attempt is to store the result sets into a temp table then select the one you want. (If you cannot change the proc)

Comment: do you want to use C# DataSet to solve this issue..?

Comment: My question is to get table from sp that has multi select statements. I want to execute it through sql server only. not through other languages like C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass input variable and use if statment. For example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE multiple
@choice INT
AS
BEGIN
   IF (@choice = 1)
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM Table1
   END
   IF (@choice = 2)
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM Table2
   END
   IF (@choice = 3)
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM Table1
      SELECT * FROM Table2
   END
END
```

And execution of procedure:

```
EXECUTE multiple @choice = 1 -- to use 1st select

EXECUTE multiple @choice = 2 -- to use 2st select

EXECUTE multiple @choice = 3 -- to use both selects
```

Comment: i think it's not what he's looking for.

Comment: I think this solution should work If I correctly understood question.

Comment: It seems it will work. But I can't add extra parameters to the SP.Is there any alternative method that fulfills my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use TEMP table to fill all result in the temp table.

if you have 3 table name tab_1,tab_2,tab_3 then create a temp table with column maximum from these table(tab_1,tab_2,tab_3) and add a extra column to temp table to identify data from tables.

```
tab_1(id bigint,name varchar(50))

tab_2(id bigint,email varchar(50))

tab_3(id bigint,address varchar(50),phone varchar(50))
```

then your temp table should be like this

```
#tmp(col1 bigint(),col2 varchar(50),col3 varchar(50),from_table varchar(50))
```

e.g

```
create table tab_1
(
  id bigint identity(1,1),
  name varchar(50),
  email varchar(50)
  )

  insert into tab_1(name,email) values
  ('a','a@mail.com'),  ('b','c@mail.com'),
    ('a1','a1@mail.com'),  ('a2','a2@mail.com'),
      ('a3','a3@mail.com'),  ('a4','a4@mail.com'),
      ('b1','b1@mail.com'),('b2','b2@mail.com')


     create table tab_2
(
  id bigint identity(1,1),
  name varchar(50),
  email varchar(50),
  amount decimal(18,2)

  ) 
    insert into tab_2(name,email,amount) values
  ('a','a@mail.com',12.5),  ('b','c@mail.com',11.6),
    ('a1','a1@mail.com',11.7),  ('a2','a2@mail.com',88.9),
      ('a3','a3@mail.com',90),  ('a4','a4@mail.com',45),
      ('b1','b1@mail.com',78),('b2','b2@mail.com',88)
```

and the Sp should be like

```
create table #tab(col1 bigint,
col2 varchar(50),
col3 varchar(50),col4 varchar(50),table_from varchar(50))

insert into #tab(col1,col2,col3,table_from) 
select id,name,email,'table_1' from tab_1

insert into #tab(col1,col2,col3,col4,table_from) 
select id,name,email,amount,'table_2' from tab_2

select * from #tab
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73bf0/3)